# Dynamically size block element when overlapped by float

Tags: html, css

Given a block element and a float that sits to the right of it, how can I ensure the block element doesn't overlap the float when space is constrained? Here's an example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yn2gbuuh/)):

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class='goodContainer'>
    <div class='floater'>Image Placeholder</div>
    <p class='header'>Header is here</p>
</div>
<br/>
<div class='badContainer'>
    <div class='floater'>Image Here</div>
    <p class='header'>Header is here</p>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.goodContainer {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.badContainer {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.header {
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 70%;
}

.floater {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

In the first box (green border) there's enough space to allow the header and image to coexist peacefully. In the second (red box) space starts to get constrained and they begin to overlap. Is there any way I can make the header resize dynamically in this case as to not overlap the image? I'm open to changing whatever is needed to make it work while keeping the general appearance (specifically that it preserves the proper width of the header when available).

Comment: For the answer TL;DR: Adding a right margin on the block element itself allows it to dynamically resize when encroached by the float as long as it doesn't have a fixed width (max-width is ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this one:

```
.header {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: 100px;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5bpgrcq9/6/